# disable restore version in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint-2010, versioning

is there any solution to remove or disabled the restore option in version page, since i don't want the user to see the versions but not be able to restore it.
any suggestions

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Restore context menu item is added in the AddVersionMenuItemsCore function in core.js.

Here is the code that adds the item:

```
if (HasRights(0x0, 0x4))
{
    menuOption=CAMOpt(m, L_RestoreVersion_Text, "javascript:RestoreVersion()", "");
    menuOption.id="ID_RestoreVersion";
}
```

So it appears the only way to allow users to view versions but prevent them from restoring previous versions is to grant them ViewVersions permission but make sure they do not have EditListItems permissions. See [SPBasePermissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx) for more information.